# Function inside append method

Tags: jquery, function, append, conditional-statements

I would like to know if it is possible in jQuery, to add a condition inside the `.append()` function

```
$.each(result, function (i, item) {
  $('.body-recap').append('<div class="recap event-name b-primary row">\n' +
  // some condition
```

and at the and, inside the append, check if `item['value'] === null`, so do this or do that.

The things is I don't see how to do it if it's not inside the append function,
because I need to check a precise `item['value']`, if I try to do it after the append function, it replace only the first element, but I cannot know which element will have this value, so I don't have other choice to make a condition inside the append.

Comment: Put the condition *outside* the `append()` and use it to set tthe value of a string variable. Then concatenate that variable to the string in `append()`

Answer (score 0):

You can include a function inside `.append()`. However, if you just want to check `item['value']` in your `$.each` function to determine what should be done, why don't you just do something like the following to change the appended div content based on item value?

```
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
  var newDiv = '<div class="classnames">'; 
  if(item['value']) {
    newDiv += 'text if item value is truthy</div>';
  }else{
    newDiv += 'text if item value is falsy</div>';
  }
  $('.body-recap').append(newDiv);
});
```

Comment: Tanks for the responses guys